# Angular nested ng-repeat IE8

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui, ui-select2, angularjs-select2

I'm trying to render some JSON data using angular ng-repeat directive. It's an array of items and every item has array of tags along with other item data.
I'm using angular-ui/select-ui to render tags with select2. Select2 element uses an array of available tags (tagList) predefined in angular controller:

```
<ui-select multiple ng-model="element.tags" ng-change="addTag(element.tags, $index)" theme="select2">
    <ui-select-match ui-lock-choice="$item.locked" placeholder="Add new tag..." value="Add new tag...">
        <div style="color: {{$item.color}};">
            {{$item.label}}
        </div>
    </ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices refresh="refreshTags($select.search, element.itemTags, $index)" refresh-delay="0"
                       repeat="tag in tagList[$index] | filter: $select.search">
        <div ng-bind-html="tag.label | filter: $select.search"></div>
        <small>
            {{tag.description}}
        </small>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

The problem is in IE8 and it's not consistent:

- {{tag.description}} and/or tag.label are not handled by angular and printed as is in dropdown choices list.
- Placeholder ("Add new tag...") is not rendered in IE8 and IE9

Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks.

refreshTags:

```
$scope.refreshTags = function (term, tags, index)
{
    var labels = [];
    $scope.tagList[index] = $scope.tagSource;

    tags.forEach(function (item) {
        labels.push(item.label);
    });

    if (labels.length) {
        $scope.tagList[index] = $scope.tagList[index].filter(function(tag) {
            return labels.indexOf(tag.label) == -1;
        });
    }

    if (term.length) {
        $scope.tagList[index] = $scope.tagList[index].filter(function(tag) {
            return tag.label.indexOf(term) > -1;
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: `repeat="tag in tagList[$index] | filter: $select.search"` ? Should be `ng-repeat="..."`

Comment: No, it should be "repeat":
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/ui-select-choices

Comment: Which version of angularjs do you use? For the second point, the placeholder attribute is not supported in IE 8 and 9: http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder

Comment: @Gets I'm using 1.2.26
You comment explains me why second issue exists... Thanks!